# Cannot change read/write permissions on script file /usr/local/bin code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, permissions

So I recently updated my Mac to iOS Ventura. Since then I am unable to type "code ." into my terminal to open vs code in whatever directory I am in. The error I get is:

`/usr/local/bin/code: line 6: python: command not found /usr/local/bin/code: line 10: ./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory` 
I saw a solution [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141819) and the same one somewhere else.

However, when I try was in /usr/local/bin and typed "nano code" I was unable to edit the file. I got the error `[ cannot open file for writing: read-only file system ]`. I also tried dragging the file into VS code but I had a similar read/write issue. I am also unable to edit the permissions when I right click on the file and hit "get info". There is no option to edit. I also tried changing the permissions on that file using chmod to no avail. It's driving me nuts that I don't have read/write permission for files on my own computer. Does anyone have an idea of how I can have writing permissions on this file?

Answer (score 0):

I do know for the `/usr/local/bin/code: line 6: python: command not found` you can run `sudo vim /usr/local/bin/code` and then add 3 to the end of python on this line `function realpath() { python<3> -c "import...` I guess the new mac update does not support python 2 anymore so you have to specify 3. Still looking into the line 10 error. If I figure it out I will post here again.

Comment: Ok, so I believe your /usr/local/bin/code is outdated. I tried updating it a few different ways with no luck. I just completely deleted my vscode and then reinstalled it `rm -rf ~/.vscode` `rm -rf <vscode from applications` and then rm `/usr/local/bin/code` then reinstall vscode for mac and in your new vscode run `cmd shft p` type in code and choose the `install code` that will generate the new `/usr/local/bin/code` for you and it should work.